# Disc brake performance fluid

Tags: brakes

I own a mountain bike with mechanical disc brakes that seriously lack stopping power. I've tried tweaking things and replacing pads but always fell short on performance. I ride more on the road but sometimes offroad. I was just wondering: Does a fluid for making disc brakes "grab" better exist?

Comment: Have you tried bigger rotors? What bike and terrain do you ride?

Comment: Do you mean a fluid for 'washing' the disc pad and rotor, or the hydraulic fluid?

Comment: Brake cleaning fluid or alcohol!

Comment: Well trains have a pipe that drops sand in front of the wheels to increase friction. You can all head over to Kickstarter for my Iron Rooster Disc Friction Enhancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not that I have ever heard of. Any liquid on the rotor or pad would tend to act as a lubricant and get worn or washed off anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Mechanical or hydraulic brakes ?

If mechanical, maybe the cables are not tight enough ? or too used ?
If hydraulic, maybe there's a leak in the system ?

In both cases, maybe the pads are too worn out ? 
maybe the brakes rotors themselves are dirty or worn out or have some oil/grease/dirt on them, clean them out.

Have a looksie at :